# Multiple Nginx Ingress configuration with same hostname annotations/TLS problem

Tags: nginx, ssl, kubernetes, annotations, hostname

I have an application accessed via hostA.com and a path '/' defined. This application needs annotations:

```
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: ca1  
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: optional
```

Also, I need to access the same application via the same hostname on a special URL '/v8/something/abc' with https:// but without client authentication, so I need to remove the annotations for TLS. I tried with two different Ingress objects, but it doesn't work because the other Ingress is ignored. Merge does not work because it does not accept TLS annotations. Does anyone know how to configure this?
These below are my ingress objects:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: mynamespace/my-ca
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: optional
  name: ingressA
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hosta.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: http
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - hosta.com
    secretName: mysecret

--- 

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: off
  name: ingressB
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hosta.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: http
        path: /v8/something/abc
  tls:
   - hosts:
    - hosta.com
    secretName: mysecret
```

Comment: What is your cloud provider ? Can you provide service yaml file ?

Comment: Azure is my cloud provider. What service file ? Ingress or myservice   service yaml ?

Comment: Please provide your service yaml file - not ingress.